# imagepullbackoff while pulling image from azure container registry

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes

First i have created the docker image and created kubernetes cluster in azure container service.
Then tag and push the image to my repository, but while pulling my image from azure container registry to kubernetes cluster the pod are created but in status it shows imagepullback off

The yaml file for basic api image

```
**apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: myapis
spec:
  containers:
    - name: myapis
      image: ciqsample.azurecr.io/myapis
  imagePullSecrets:
    - name: samplekey**
```

Comment: see you can pull the image with docker first 'docker run ciqsample.azurecr.io/myapis'

Answer (score 8):

You might need to attach with container registry itself.

```
az aks update -n myAKSCluster -g myResourceGroup --attach-acr $MYACR
```

$MYACR -> name of the container registry without ".azurecr.io" postfix

Answer (score 5):

This error means we use wrong key and password to pull image.
Can you run this command to **check** secret exist or not?`kubectl get secret`

```
root@k8s-master-BBF71727-0:~# kubectl get secret
NAME                  TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
azurecr               kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1         57m
default-token-clm2d   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         2h
```

Then **check** the secret.

```
root@k8s-master-BBF71727-0:~# kubectl get secret azurecr --output=yaml
```

We can use this command script to **create** secret:

```
kubectl create secret docker-register yoursecretname --docker-server=jason.azurecr.io/xxxx/test --docker-username={UserName} --docker-password={Password} --docker-email=team@domain.com
```

By the way, for test please [**login**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli#log-in-to-a-registry) Azure container registry with your registry credentials, then try to pull image from Azure container registry.
**Login**
`docker login myregistry.azurecr.io -u xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -p myPassword`

**Pull** the image from your registry

```
docker pull myregistry.azurecr.io/samples/nginx
```