# Deploying Windows Containers (created with Docker) into Azure Container Service

Tags: azure, docker

I am trying to complete an architectural research on how to properly work with Windows Containers within the Azure domain/environment where I have to containerize the Dot Net Core Web API application and deploy that container into an Azure Container Service

Here are the things that I did

1. I did create an Azure Container Service account/domain/virtual machine within the Azure portal
2. Also, I did create another virtual machine for the Windows Server 2016 with Containers that already had the Docker installed
3. On the Windows server 2016 I did create a simple .NET Core Web API application and created an image for that application using Docker
4. I did push the image of the Web API application into a Docker hub and using the SSH tunnel interface tried to download the image into an Azure Container Service, so it can be run from that service

However, I would get a message that the Windows Containers cannot run on Linux as the Azure Container Service by default is a Linux system

Is there a way to deploy a Windows Docker Container into an Azure Container Service
 a. Should I create Azure Container Service in Windows?
 b. Should I use another orchestrator (NOT Docker) to deploy a Windows Container into an Azure Container Service?
 c. Should I go down a different path?

Thank you very much in advance for your kind support!

Comment: Azure container service? which orchestrator are you choose? Kubernetes?

Comment: We are choosing docker swarm, thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the Windows Containers cannot run on Linux as the Azure Container
>   Service by default is a Linux system.

As we know, container about Linux and windows are different, so we can't run windows container on Linux system.

As a workaround, we can create Azure container service(choose kubernetes) with windows agent, so we can deploy windows container to kubernetes windows agent.

We can via Azure portal to deploy Azure container service, select orchestrator to kubernetes, at agent configuration, we should select operating system to windows. In this way, the master of kubernetes is Linux, and the agent is windows.

We can use `kubectl` and docker file to create windows container.
For example, we can deploy IIS container on windows agent. Kubernetes is a tool which use to manage containers, so we can use k8s to deploy IIS to windows nodes.

1.create `iis.json` file, like this:

```
{
 "apiVersion": "v1",
 "kind": "Pod",
 "metadata": {
   "name": "iis",
   "labels": {
     "name": "iis"
   }
 },
 "spec": {
   "containers": [
     {
       "name": "iis",
       "image": "nanoserver/iis",
       "ports": [
         {
         "containerPort": 80
         }
       ]
     }
   ],
   "nodeSelector": {
    "beta.kubernetes.io/os": "windows"
    }
  }
}
```

2.use kubctl apply command to create pods, like this:

```
kubectl apply -f iis.json
```

More information about how to use k8s to deploy a windows IIS container, please refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/kubernetes/container-service-kubernetes-windows-walkthrough).

If you want to use your container image, you can upload your image to [Azure container registry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-get-started-docker-cli), then pull the image from your registry.

How to set secret for Azure container registry and pull image, please refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44385965/imagepullbackoff-while-pulling-image-from-azure-container-registry/44406705#44406705).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  I did create a Kubernetes cluster within the Azure bash shell and able to run the kubectl command. As I understand for this environment I should be able to run containers. However, whenever I try to pull am image from a docker hub "Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?". And I can't find any information how to start the docker daemon so I could run the containers. Am I on the right path or should I not use docker command at all on Kubernetes for the Docker Windows Container?

Comment: @Mikhail Kubernetes is a tool which use to manage containers, by default, docker is running, but we should connect to K8s agent(node), in that node, we can run docker command, but we should use `kubectl` command to create and manager containers, should not use docker command.   As we know, k8s master run api and other service, not run container service, container will run on k8s agent.

Comment: @Mikhail if you want to connect to k8s agent and run docker command on it, we can create another VM(jumpbox) in the same Vnet, and ssh this VM's public IP address, then RDP to K8S agent. in that session, we can run docker command direct.

Comment: @Mikhail Just want to confirm the current situations.

Please feel free to let me know if you need further assistance.

Comment: Jason, thank you very much for your help  I did follow the instructions here and created a Kubernetes cluster for Windows where I could deploy my containers.    However, after I ran a demo for my manager, I now need to conduct an additional research as my manager has some questions     First of all. he is curious why the docker container cannot run on Windows (I do use Docker command when create the container)    After all the Docker container should be platform independent and run in any environment, on both Windows and Linux

Comment: Also, I understand that there should be a switch between Windows and Linux when running Docker builds; however, on Windows Server 2016 with Containers there is no docker switch. Only command line is available, is that possible to switch between Linux and Windows modes on the command line   and also, just in case, I am NOT working with Windows Containers, I am trying to work with Docker Containers. Is that a true statement that a Docker Container with the .Net Core application (which is also cross platform cannot run on Linux)?