# Do I need SSH tunnel to deploy Docker containers from Windows Server 2016 using Full CI/CD pipeline

Tags: azure, docker, ssh, kubernetes, docker-swarm

Thank you very much for your help with the previous questions

[Deploying Windows Containers (created with Docker) into Azure Container Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45594965/deploying-windows-containers-created-with-docker-into-azure-container-service)

[Windows Container vs Docker Container and Azure Container Services/Kubernetes cluster with Linux OS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45704536/windows-container-vs-docker-container-and-azure-container-services-kubernetes-cl/45705951)

I am continuing my research and somewhat at a standstill as I try to follow the instructions of the following article that explains how to create CI/CD pipeline to deploy a multi-container application.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-service/dcos-swarm/container-service-docker-swarm-setup-ci-cd

The code sample that is referenced here is built for the Linux application, and I am not able to run it or create Docker container out of it.

Thus, I have following questions (those questions could be all over the place, my apologies for that)

1. When I create a .Net Core Web API on Windows 2016 server, is there any possibility for me to create an application that I could deploy to a Linux environment? (portable .NET Core Web API application)
2. When I would like to take advantage of CI/CD pipeline using Visual Studio Team Services, do I really need to create Azure Container Service with Docker Swarm? As far as I understand ACS is a Linux based environment whereas I would create Windows based docker containers on Windows Server 2016
3. Do I really need to be concerned with ACS and SSH tunnel when dealing with Windows Server 2016 based docker containers if I could easily deploy those containers to a Kubernetes cluster with Windows nodes
4. Is there an alternative way for me to deploy docker containers created on Windows Server 2016 using Full CI/CD pipeline to Visual Studio Team Services without using the Linux based SSH tunnel/ACS

Thank you very much for your generous input

Mikhail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.When I create a .Net Core Web API on Windows 2016 server, is there any
>   possibility for me to create an application that I could deploy to a
>   Linux environment?

Yes, .Net core is a general purpose development platform maintained by Microsoft and the .NET community on GitHub. It is cross-platform, supporting Windows, macOS and Linux, and can be used in device, cloud, and embedded/IoT scenarios. So we can deploy .net core web api app on Linux environment.

Maybe we can refer to this [link](https://raygun.com/blog/net-core-docker-container/).

> 2.When I would like to take advantage of CI/CD pipeline using Visual
>   Studio Team Services, do I really need to create Azure Container
>   Service with Docker Swarm?

No, creating a CI/CD pipeline on Azure Container service with kubernetes and visual studio team services is available. More information about VSTS and ACS k8s, please refer to this [link](https://dgkanatsios.com/2017/05/29/creating-a-cicd-pipeline-on-azure-container-services-with-kubernetes-and-visual-studio-team-services/).

> 3.Do I really need to be concerned with ACS and SSH tunnel when dealing with Windows Server 2016 based docker containers if I could
>   easily deploy those containers to a Kubernetes cluster with Windows
>   nodes

If you want to use VSTS to deploy your .net core container, I think we should connect to ACS cluster.

If you want to use ACS k8s, we should add kubernetes connection:

[image]

> 4.Is there an alternative way for me to deploy docker containers created on Windows Server 2016 using Full CI/CD pipeline to Visual
>   Studio Team Services without using the Linux based SSH tunnel/ACS

Do you mean you want to use ACS, but don't want to connect Linux based SSH tunnel? If I am right, we can deploy a site-to-site VPN between your on-prem network and Azure Vnet, in this way, we can connect k8s like local.